# How to remove an apostrophe ( ' ) from couple of columns of a .CSV file?

Tags: text-processing, sed, awk, csv

I have a .CSV file with 7 fields, and the 3rd and 4th columns of the file has a number starting with an apostrophe ( ' ). Please see the example below.

```
col0,col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6,
1value0,1value1,'8972991766941,'8972991766941,1value4,1value5,1value6,
2value0,2value1,'8912988876583,'8912988876583,2value4,2value5,2value6,
3value,3value1,'8912981226981,'8912981226981,3value4,3value5,3value6,
2value0,4value1,'8912971783681,'8912971783681,4value4,4value5,4value6,
```

How do I get rid of the apostrophes in the 3rd and 4th columns only using either sed or awk?

Comment: I tried to use the below command but not working... 

sed 's/'//g' file
and
sed 's/,'//g' file

Comment: `tr -d \'`, note this will delete all single quotes in all columns.

Comment: @Kevin Even I thought of using `tr` however, as I cannot pass a specific column or field position in that command, I backed off...

Comment: the final step is to buy a sledge-hammer and smash the keyboard of whoever gave you that broken non-CSV file so they can never do it again.  say "next time, it's your hands" while doing it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it with `awk`, The idea is to run a [sub](http://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~oostr102/docs/nawk/nawk_92.html)stitute command on columns 3 and 4 to replace the single quote with a blank. Here `\047` represents the octal code for `'`.

```
 awk -F, -v OFS=, '{sub(/\047/, "", $3); sub(/\047/, "", $4); print}' file.txt
```

Comment: I am just a beginner in **`sed`** and **`awk`** Could you please explain the substitution part in your code above? Confused with the back slash and forward slash used. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Dhruuv, if it's any easier and if your requirement translates to stripping all single quotes from the file regardless of their position, I have added a `tr` alternative. Note the `047` represents the octal value for `'`

Comment: `tr` would make it more complex as I do not want the apostrophes in other columns to be replaced.

Comment: @Dhruuv, replaced the original awk code with a readabl version. Here `\047` represents the octal code for `'`. So substitute `'` with a blank in fields 3 and 4 and then print the line

Answer (score 2):

Use the other quote quaracter

```
sed "s/'//g" file
```

or end quoting, escape the apostrophe and start quoting again

```
sed 's/'\''//g' file
```

in this case there are no quotes necessary except for the apostrophe that hasa special meaning for the shell

```
sed s/\'//g file
```

this can also be done using the double quotes

```
sed s/"'"//g file
```

I realized after I read the comments to this post that I did not solve the original question but corrected a command postet in a comment by the OP.

Comment: Thank you for the different answers. I tried to use the first code, and it is throwing me an error as below 

`sed: -e expression #1, char 5: unterminated s command`

second code worked fine, but the code needs to be modified into `sed 's/'\''//g' file`

Third one also worked fine, but the code needs to be modified into `sed 'sed s/\'//g file`

Comment: First one needs another `/`

Comment: @miracle173, @Kevin: The code works, but it is replacing all the apostrophes in the file... Is there a way, I can replace the apostrophes only in the 3rd and 4th fields of the file using `sed`? Using `awk` it can be done as the solution stated by @1_CR...

Comment: @Dhruuv Yes, it can be done in sed, but it's not pretty. You're better off with `awk`, it was designed for delimited text files like this. In case you really want to see, `sed 's/\([^,]*,[^,]*,\)'\''\([^,]*,\)'\''/\1\2/' test.in` or `sed -E "s/(([^,]*,){2})'([^,]*,)'/\1\2/" test.in` (Depending on your sed version, you may need to change `-E` to `-r`).

Comment: @Kevin: Thanks Kevin, very helpful... I just wanted to see if we can achieve this in `sed` just for the columns 3 and 4... I will go ahead with `awk` then... :)